# Why size() runs faster than length() when querying for the length of the path between two distant vertices?

Tags: postgresql, graph-databases, apache-age, opencypher

I have a graph with multiple vertices and each of them represent an article from Wikipedia. The edges represent which article the first link of the current article text leads to. The article that is related to every other article is "Philosophy". I have 27 vertices and 26 edges.

If I want to see how far one edge is away from the other, I can query it in two different ways: one is using the `size()` function and the other is using the `length()` function. But one thing that I noted is that when we use `size()` instead of `length()` the query runs almost twice as fast. Why does that happen?

```sql
demo=# \timing on
Timing is on.

demo=# SELECT * FROM cypher('Wikipedia', $$
MATCH p = (a)-[e:RELATED_TO*]->(b)
WHERE a.name = 'Tulpa' AND b.name = 'Philosophy'
RETURN size(e)
$$) AS (edge_count agtype);
 edge_count 
------------
 18
(1 row)

Time: 4.724 ms

demo=# SELECT * FROM cypher('Wikipedia', $$
MATCH p = (a)-[e:RELATED_TO*]->(b)
WHERE a.name = 'Tulpa' AND b.name = 'Philosophy'
RETURN length(p)
$$) AS (edge_count agtype);
 edge_count 
------------
 18
(1 row)

Time: 7.280 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong.

According to the [Apache AGE docs](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/functions/scalar_functions.html#length), the `size()` function returns the length of a list (array), while `length()` returns the length of a path. After reading the source code for `age_size` and `age_length` in the [AGE Repository](https://github.com/apache/age/blob/master/src/backend/utils/adt/agtype.c), as well as each array returned by the query, it appears that the `length()` function retrieves the path array, checks for a path, and calculates the length by subtracting one from the number of elements (edges + vertices) and dividing by 2.

I believe the `length()` function, which creates a path using the AGE type AGTV_PATH, is more computationally expensive than size(), which simply checks the type of its values and counts the length of an array or a string (since the function supports inputs such as cstrings, text, and the agtype string or list).

Comment: The functions that are called inside the cypher query are not the age_size() and age_length(). They are the scalar functions of cypher neoj4: [neoj4 scalar functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar).
If you want to use the functions you provided it needs to be outside of the query, something like this 
`demo=# SELECT age_size(edge_count) FROM cypher('Wikipedia', $$
MATCH p = (a)-[e:RELATED_TO*]->(b)
WHERE a.name = 'Tulpa' AND b.name = 'Philosophy'
RETURN e
$$) AS (edge_count agtype) ;`

Answer (score 0):

"p" contains information about the vertices throughout the path and holds more information.
In contrast "e" only has information about the relationship so im assuming calculating the size of "p" and "e" comes down to the size of each variable and not specifically about the size() and length() functions.

Answer (score 0):

**size()** calculates the relationships between two vertices (*Tulpa* and *Philosophy* in this case) without traversing the complete path.

While **length()** calculates the complete length of the path by traversing it completely and in addition, it also calculates the number of relationships that comes in that path. Therefore, it takes more time than size().

Due to this reason, size() it runs faster than length().